# PowerShell JSON Date TO FILETIME(C++)

Tags: json, powershell, visual-c++

Hi I am getting JSON DATE from powershell. Which is like "Date(1536995530875)" I really could not understand this numbers. 
In my C++ program I have string LPCWSTR date = Date(1536995530875)
How can I get FileTime or SystemTime from this string.

Thanks in advance
Santhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1536995530875 is the number of milliseconds since the 1/1/1970 [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)).

This will return a valid Powershell `[datetime]`:

```
$dt = New-Object DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
$dt.AddMilliseconds(1536995530875)
```

Comment: As sidenote, this will leave the `.Kind` property of the date to `Unspecified`, which will result in actions like `$dtToLocalTime()` always look upon this date as being UTC, even when it was a local time already. To overcome that, you need to figure out if the date supplied is UTC or Local time and add that to the creation of the variable: `$dt = New-Object DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Utc')` or `$dt = New-Object DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Local')`